# Getting $rootScope.ons.navigator as undefined in Onsen UI

Tags: onsen-ui

I want to handle android's back button to popPage and ask confirmation for exit App but getting ons.navigator object as undefined.

Thus, I am unable to use getPages() and getCurrentPage().

Please help!!!

I am using 5 templates. Out of which three templates are pushed hence no  element. Rest 2 templates are tabbar based. JUST for mre info.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What version of Onsen UI are you using? In Onsen UI 1.3 and later the `ons.navigator` variable has been removed. Instead you can use the `var` attribute:

```
<ons-navigator var="myNav">
  ...
</ons-navigator>
```

To access the navigator you use the `$scope.myNav` variable:

```
$scope.myNav.getCurrentPage();
```

The `ons.navigator` variable was removed since it will behave strangely when defining more than one navigator.